# In inheritance can we by pass viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, inheritance, viewdidload

I have a UIViewController_A.
I this view controller's vidDidLoad I have a http request for getting some data.

I inherited UIViewController_A and created UIViewController_B.
Now can I bypass the [super viewdDidLoad]; in UIViewController_B.

Because if I call [super viewdDidLoad]; in xxx_B then it is making http call from xxx_A, and I don't want this.

Comment: What is the actual question ?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @George: is this really necessary to call super.viewDidLoad() in child class?

Answer (score 4):

`viewDidLoad()` method should always call `super.viewDidLoad()`. Not doing it may cause the controller to not instantiate correctly.

Instead, you can override the desired behaviour of the parent controller. For example:

```
class ParentController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        performOperation()
    }

    func performOperation() {
        print("Calling WebService from ParentController")
    }
}

class ChildController: ParentController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // <--- ALWAYS REQUIRED
        // Custom initialization
    }

    override func performOperation() {
        print("Overriding parent operation so it doesn't call the WebService")
    }
}
```

Comment: the user does not want to run the function you are doing what the user does not want to do

Comment: No, the parent function is not being called at all.

Comment: that I am asking, if I dont call parent viewDidLoad so is that correct?

Comment: You should always call `super.viewDidLoad` when overriding it. You can't skip that part. What you can do is override the webservice method call so it doesn't make the actual call in the child controller.

Comment: @redent84 I was under the impression that `UIViewController.viewDidLoad()` does nothing, and it's just a convenient place to initialize the subviews. So if your custom view controller is a direct subclass of `UIViewController`, calling `super` has no effect. The current documentation does not mention either way. Of course, in the general case that there are intermediate subclasses, skipping it is risky.

Comment: @NicolasMiari I'm not sure that the default implementation of viewDidLoad is empty, but Apple may change it anytime, so relying on that current implementation may break your application on future iOS releases.